# I want to find maximum number in sql server i have values with string part and integer part

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, max, resultset

I have values like `SP-1`,`SP-2`,`SP-3`.....`SP-10`,`SP-11`.

I have to get the maximum number from here in my SQL server

```
SELECT MAX(SUBSTRING(SupplementId,4,10)) AS max_num FROM supreg
```

When I execute the code I get the maximum number as 9.

Comment: how about showing us something we can use to help you. Like sample data for example ?

Comment: @GuidoG - the sample data is there, although not tabularized.

Comment: The reason that you're getting this result is that the `SUBSTRING` function returns a string. Although the characters in these substrings are in the range '0' through '9', it is still a string, not a number, and when strings are compared they are compared character-by-character. Thus, the substrings which are returned are '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', and '11'. When these strings are compared, one character at a time, the string with the "largest value" is '9'. I hope this helps.

Comment: You need to cast your substring to int after that you can get max number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(SupplementId,4,10) AS INT)) AS max_num FROM supreg
```

or

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(REPLACE(SupplementId,'SP-','') AS INT)) AS max_num FROM supreg
```

Comment: but it stops in 10 i want to go 11 12 ,13 like wise

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use the length:

```
SELECT TOP 1 sr.*
FROM supreg sr
ORDER BY length(SupplementId) DESC, SupplementId DESC;
```

This allows you to get the entire row with the largest value.

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirement you could use

```
 Select Max(substr ( tb_simple.sampleValues ,4  )  ) as maxValue from tb_simple
```

[image]

Comment: you could replace substr() with SUBSTRING( ) for SQL server